# Power Query join on the least difference

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

How to make a Power Query join of two tables on least difference between columns. I mean absolute difference between numbers.

[image]

I followed this great article: https://exceed.hr/blog/merging-with-date-range-using-power-query/

I tried adding this custom column analogously, where L stands for Tab1 and R for Tab2:

```
= Table.AddColumn(
    Source, 
    "LeastAbsDifference", 
    (L) =>
      Table.SelectRows( Tab2, 
         (R) => L[category] = R[category] and Number.Abs(L[target] - R[actual]) )
  )
```

It produces error:
Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value 4 to type Logical.

---

Tables to recreate example:

```
// Tab1
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclTSUTJVitWJVnKCs5whrFgA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [category = _t, target = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"target", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

```
// Tab2
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclTSUTJUitWBsIzgLGMwywnIMoGzTOEsM6XYWAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [category = _t, actual = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"actual", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: (R) => L[category] = R[category] and Number.Abs(L[target] - R[actual]) )  will not work because Number.Abs() will return a number and therefore the Table.SelectRow function will look for matching categories and #.  You cant say "Look at table for 4" which is what you are doing.  There is no way for this type of formula to find the closest number with a select, you need to use something similar to Rons

Comment: @horseyride Yes, you are right. I need to find a MIN of Number.Abs(L[target] - R[actual]) or add it as a new column to results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to acknowledge a favor of Kristian Rados, who provided the answer to my question in the comments of his article: [Merging with date range using Power Query](https://exceed.hr/blog/merging-with-date-range-using-power-query/) With my gratitude, and by courtesy of the author, I am quoting the answer in full:

---

The reason your formula produces an error is the second argument of the Table.SelectRows function. In it, you need to filter the table with the boolean (true/false) expression. In your case, the part of the code with Number.Abs function returns a number instead of true/false (e.g. L[target] – R[actual] = 5-1=4 ). Trying to filter the table this way could be possible, but it would require you to use multiple nested environments, which would result in a very complicated formula and slow performance.

I would suggest trying a different approach. By using your example from stack overflow I reproduced the problem. Below is a complete M code I came up with along with the explanation below:

```
let
    Source = Tab1,
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"category"}, Tab2, {"category"}, "Tab2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Tab2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Tab2", {"actual"}, {"actual"}),
    #"Inserted Subtraction" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Tab2", "Least difference", each Number.Abs([target] - [actual]), Int64.Type),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Inserted Subtraction", {"category"}, {{"All", each Table.First(Table.Sort(_, {{"Least difference", Order.Ascending}}))}}),
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "All", {"target", "actual", "Least difference"}, {"target", "actual", "Least difference"})
in
    #"Expanded All"
```

First, we merged the queries by using the category column. After expanding the table, we subtracted two columns to get the absolute difference between target and actual. Finally, we group by category and sort the table by the Least difference column in ascending order (Table.Sort function inside the grouped rows). After this, we take the first row of the nested table (Table.First function), and finally expand the record column.

---

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

- Append the two tables
- Group by Category
- Output the desired columns as a Group aggregation

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclTSUTJVitWJVnKCs5whrFgA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), 
        Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [category = _t, target = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"target", Int64.Type}}),
    Source2 = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclTSUTJUitWBsIzgLGMwywnIMoGzTOEsM6XYWAA=", 
        BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [category = _t, actual = _t]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"actual", Int64.Type}}),


//append the tables
    append = Table.Combine({#"Changed Type",#"Changed Type1"}),

//Group by category, then output the desired columns
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(append, {"category"}, {
        {"target", each [target]{0},Int64.Type},
        
        {"actual", (t)=> t[actual]{
            List.PositionOf(List.Transform(t[actual], each Number.Abs(t[target]{0} - _)),
                List.Min(List.Transform(t[actual], each Number.Abs(t[target]{0} - _))),Occurrence.First)},Int64.Type},
        
        {"least difference", (t)=> List.Min(List.Transform(t[actual], each Number.Abs(t[target]{0} - _))),Int64.Type
        
        }})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

***Output from above code***
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I would like to avoid append because in real case the two tables have lots of different columns. A solution of adding a single column with table content seems more tempting. And I think that my try is close to it.

Comment: I value educational aspect of your answer. Thank you.